# Exception if any value in the array passed as an argument is less than 0

Tags: java, processing

TRYING TO: Given the sample code HW7C Alter the code to throw a IllegalArgumentException
exception if ANY value in the array passed as an argument is less than 0. Change the
declaration so the programmer calling this function is forced to deal with this
IllegalArgumentException.

(Does not mark as incorrect, comes up as HW7C is incorrect) Code tried so far:

```
public int HW7C (int numbers[]) {

//iterate through all elements in numbers array

if(numbers.length > 0 ) {

    for (int number : numbers) {
        if(number < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: anyone?? help with this please

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the declaration of the method. By changing the declaration it specifies that it can throw IllegalArgumentException exception which must be handled by the caller.

The code should be like this,

```
public int HW7C (int numbers[]) throws IllegalArgumentException {

//iterate through all elements in numbers array

if(numbers.length > 0 ) {

    for (int number : numbers) {
        if(number < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is an unchecked exception, so it doesn't necessarily need to be handled by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to throw checked exception. If thrown exception has to be named `IllegalArgumentException` then create your own exception class which extends `Exception` and simply name it `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
package org.yourorgname.exception;

public class IllegalArgumentException extends Exception {
    //class body
}
```

```
public int HW7C (int numbers[]) throws org.yourorgname.exception.IllegalArgumentException {

   //iterate through all elements in numbers array

    if(numbers.length > 0 ) {

        for (int number : numbers) {
            if(number < 0) {
                throw new org.yourorgname.exception.IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```